# How to Block All Outside Links on a Wordpress game website

Tags: php, html, hyperlink, wordpress

I am setting a game website (http://arenatech.besaba.com/) and would like to block or render all links pointing outside my website useless as no been able to link outside when users click on them. I am embeding the games using myarcadeplugin pro on wordpress. For a better Idea of what I am talking about, check this website ([Friv) as you would see when you click on the game you want to play, the website in that game when clicked does not link to the website listed. Hope I could implement the same thing on my wordpress website.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to block all links (in articles included) or just in comments?

Comment: I want to block all links in the post,comment and also in the embeded flash games so it won't be able to link to other website

Comment: There is possibility to block links inside post and comments but not chance to block links im flash games.

Comment: That was what I thought at first but this website (friv . com) when you visit and select the game you want to play, all the links in the flash game like 'more games' and also the gamepreloader with external websites links when click does not link to other website.